# "Image not valid, but TextSearch is switched off!" error - Sikuli on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, automation, sikuli

I am trying to automate a desktop application on Mac using Sikuli and Eclipse.

Source code:

```
import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed;
import org.sikuli.script.ImagePath;
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;

public class TextEditorExample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FindFailed {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Screen s=new Screen();
System.out.println(ImagePath.getBundlePath());
 s.click("spotlight_icon.png");
 s.find("spotlight.png");
 s.type("spotlight.png","finder");
 s.click("applications.png");
 s.click("texteditor_icon.png");
 s.find("texteditor.png");
 s.type("texteditor.png","Sikuli Example");

 }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error :

```
[error] Image: Image not valid, but TextSearch is switched off!
[error] RunTimeAPI: Wait: Abort: unknown
[error] RunTimeAPI: ImageMissing: spotlight_icon.png
```

Path of sikuli script:

```
  /Users/adamin/Desktop/Automation/SikuliExample/src/TextEditorExample.java
```

Path of Images:

```
/Users/adamin/Desktop/Automation/SikuliExample/src/spotlight_icon.png
/Users/adamin/Desktop/Automation/SikuliExample/src/spotlight.png
/Users/adamin/Desktop/Automation/SikuliExample/src/applications.png
/Users/adamin/Desktop/Automation/SikuliExample/src/texteditor_icon.png
/Users/adamin/Desktop/Automation/SikuliExample/src/texteditor.png
```

Can anybody help me in solving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The imagepath is set by default to your project root folder and will only look for patterns there. Just set the bundle path manually to wherever your files are:

```
ImagePath.setBundlePath("fullpath");
```

Alternatively, place your files to whatever folder that is returned by:

```
System.out.println(ImagePath.getBundlePath());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Pattern.

```
Pattern pattern = new Pattern(path+"spotlight_icon.png");
Screen s=new Screen();
        try {
            s.click(pattern);
        } catch (FindFailed e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This Error most probably comes when image is not loadable, Meanwhile, use this approach

```
try{
    String path = "path of your image";
    Pattern target = new Pattern(path);
    Screen scr = new Screen();
    scr.click(target);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Y